# Rails artifact when changing the arrangement of elements in the form of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

When you change the items in the form of an artifact appears , help me to understand what is the reason ?

**view project#show:**

```
<div class="container">

    <h3><%= @project.name %></h3>

  <h2>Tasks</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped" id="tasks_list">
    <%= render @project.tasks %>
  </table>

  <h2>Add a task:</h2>
  <%= render 'tasks/form'  %>

  <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>

</div>
```

[screenshot#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMMcH.png)

If you change tasks list and add from:

```
<div class="container">

    <h3><%= @project.name %></h3>

  <h2>Add a task:</h2>
  <%= render 'tasks/form'  %>

  <h2>Tasks</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped" id="tasks_list">
    <%= render @project.tasks %>
  </table>

  <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>

</div>
```

[screenshot#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YdZy.png)

Task list size has not changed - but there was a strange artifact.

## Update

**view task#_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div aria-describedby="add_project">
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control ' %>
      </div>

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <%= f.submit 'Добавить', class: 'btn btn-success btn-secondary', id: "add_project" %>
                </span>

    </div>

<% end %>
```

**Task Controller:**

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.create(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_path, success: 'Task destroyed successfully' }
      format.js {}
    end
  end

  private
  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name)
  end
```

**Project Controller:**

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @article = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Added to the form: `<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.klass.build], remote: true) do |f| %>`

**Now error:**

```
NoMethodError in Projects#show
Showing /Users/alexandr.dmitrenko/todolist/app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x007ffde19efea8>

Extracted source (around line #1):
1<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.klass.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Are you sure it didn't change? you cannot build a form for a new task without builiding new task (well you can, but it is not how it's usually done). I am gona bet in your `tasks/form` you will find `form_for @project.tasks.build` Is it correct?

Comment: @BroiSatse , I added the information in question. Please look

Comment: As I thought, posting answer.

Comment: @BroiSatse please tell me where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this bit:

```
@project.tasks.build
```

in your form. What it does it builds a new, non-saved Task record and stores it within association. Every further call to `@project.tasks` will return the usual results (from database) + this new record. What you need to do is to replace it with:

```
@project.tasks.scope.build
```

`scope` method will return new instance of the association, so it is safe to call build on it as it will not be stored anywhere and won't affect your original association object.

Comment: I add to my method `create `

` def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.klass.build(task_params)
`
. But it did not help

Comment: Create action has nothing to do with the issue, it is where you submit your form. You need to make that change in your form.

Comment: Added to the form: `<%= form_for([@project, @project.tasks.klass.build], remote: true) do |f| %>`. Now error `NoMethodError in Projects#show` `undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x007ffde19efea8>`

Comment: Ah, true. Updating answer.

Comment: Ready. Update question

Comment: Answer updated, use `scope` instead of `klass` (or use `klass.new` rather than `klass.build`)